# Store each mysql record (multiple lines) as variable in bash

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have bash script which runs a SQL query and outputs the following:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
name: danny
id: 123
age: 1
wait: 326.000000
*************************** 2. row ***************************
name: ronny
id: 1234
age: 2
wait: 21.000000
```

I'm trying to understand how can I create an array and store each record inside, for each record I want to be able to accces its params for example:

```
Person1["name"] = danny,  Person2["name"]=ronny
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of an array must be numeric. But you can use index instead of field name.
Variables are known only within the block. But with a simple trick (sourcen) you get them to the outside.

```
# ASSUMPTION: the input data are in the file

Personen=$(mktemp)
i=0
while read line; do
    [[ "${line:0:1}" == '*' ]] && continue
    key=${line%%:*}
    value=${line##*: }
    [[ "$key" == "name" ]] && ((i++))
    echo "Person_${key}[$i]=\"$value\""
done < file >$Personen

source $Personen

echo "${Person_name[1]} ${Person_age[1]}"
echo "${Person_name[2]} ${Person_wait[2]}"

rm $Personen
```

output

```
danny 1
ronny 21.000000
```